# spark group multiple rdd items by key

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have rdd items like:

```
(3922774869,10,1)
(3922774869,11,1)
(3922774869,12,2)
(3922774869,13,2)
(1779744180,10,1)
(1779744180,11,1)
(3922774869,14,3)
(3922774869,15,2)
(1779744180,16,1)
(3922774869,12,1)
(3922774869,13,1)
(1779744180,14,1)
(1779744180,15,1)
(1779744180,16,1)
(3922774869,14,2)
(3922774869,15,1)
(1779744180,16,1)
(1779744180,17,1)
(3922774869,16,4)
...
```

which represent `(id, age, count)` and I want to group those lines to generate a dataset for which each line represent the distribution of age of each id like this(`(id, age)` is uniq):

```
(1779744180, (10,1), (11,1), (12,2), (13,2) ...)
(3922774869, (10,1), (11,1), (12,3), (13,4) ...)
```

which is `(id, (age, count), (age, count) ...)`

Could some one give me a clue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can first reduce by both fields, then use groupBy:

```
rdd
  .map { case (id, age, count) => ((id, age), count) }.reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .map { case ((id, age), count) => (id, (age, count)) }.groupByKey()
```

Which returns an `RDD[(Long, Iterable[(Int, Int)])]`, for the input above it would contain these two records:

```
(1779744180,CompactBuffer((16,3), (15,1), (14,1), (11,1), (10,1), (17,1)))
(3922774869,CompactBuffer((11,1), (12,3), (16,4), (13,3), (15,3), (10,1), (14,5)))
```

Answer (score 3):

As already suggested by Tzach Zohar, you could first of all reshape your RDD to fit into a Key/Value RDD. If you have a very large dataset, I would advise you not to use `groupByKey`, in order to reduce shuffling, though it seems super easy.
For example, basing this solution on the one already posted:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

val rddById = rdd.map { case (id, age, count) => ((id, age), count) }.reduceByKey(_ + _)
val initialSet = mutable.HashSet.empty[(Int, Int)]
val addToSet = (s: mutable.HashSet[(Int, Int)], v: (Int, Int)) => s += v
val mergePartitionSets = (p1: mutable.HashSet[(Int, Int)], p2: mutable.HashSet[(Int, Int)]) => p1 ++= p2
val uniqueByKey = rddById.aggregateByKey(initialSet)(addToSet, mergePartitionSets)
```

This will result in

```
uniqueByKey: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(AnyVal, scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[(Int, Int)])]
```

And you will be able to print the values as:

```
scala> uniqueByKey.foreach(println)
(1779744180,Set((15,1), (16,3)))
(1779744180,Set((14,1), (11,1), (10,1), (17,1)))
(3922774869,Set((12,3), (11,1), (10,1), (14,5), (16,4), (15,3), (13,3)))
```

Shuffling can be a great bottleneck. Having many big HashSet's (according to your dataset) could also be a problem. However, it's more likely that you'll have a large amount of ram (e.g., 64GB of RAM?) than network latency (and all the problems that shuffling brings along) which results in faster reads/writes across distributed machines.

To read more about [aggregateByKey](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions), have a look at this [blog post](http://codingjunkie.net/spark-agr-by-key/).

Comment: Technically, it's not the size of the dataset that's an issue, but the size of the largest key grouping (relative to your worker nodes).