# Spark core multiple column group by

Tags: java, apache-spark

I would like to perform group by operation on RDD using multiple fields with Spark Core

So far I was able to join two different RDD and group the result RDD by one column (date), But I would like to perform group by operation on more than one key/fields say (country, date).

I have already defined RDD of type `JavaRDD<ProductSale>`

```
public class ProductSale implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4579808280658565853L;

    private String country;
    private String date;
    private Double price;

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCity(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Actual data

```
country |    date   | price

Japan   |2019-04-17 | 5000.0
USA     |2019-04-16 | 10000.0
Japan   |2019-04-17 | 3000.0
UK      |2019-04-15 | 4000.0
```

Expected output

```
country |   date    | price

Japan   |2019-04-17 | 8000.0
USA     |2019-04-16 | 10000.0
UK      |2019-04-15 | 4000.0
```

Comment: I think this is a duplicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447057/spark-group-multiple-rdd-items-by-key

Comment: Hi Igor, I have already looked at duplicate question link but couldn't understand the solution. I just started learning spark, I would really appreciate if you can help me here.

Comment: Of course, according with this solution, to group by two columns, you need, at first, to build a pair RDD `((group_col_1, group_col_2), value)` through a `map()`. After this transformation, you could perform a `reduceByKey()` transformation that will group your data on this two columns and sum your value.

Comment: @user1495744 are you still looking for a Java Code for the same or have you resolved it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do the `GroupBy` operation on **multiple columns** in my solution. In this case multiple columns are `Country` and `Date`.

In the function of the `groupBy` method, we can pass just a lambda function that defines what should be the value of the group by element. We can implement a functional interface as well and pass it to this groupBy statement, but I believe passing the `lambda function` is more readable.

As mentioned in the question, I have defined an entity class that is mostly similar to the above code block. The minor difference is I have used `Lombok Annotations` for the Getter and the Constructor. So my class looks like this. It is named `ProductSaleEntity.java`

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProductSaleEntity implements Serializable {
    private final String country;
    private final String date;
    private final Double price;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProductSaleEntity{" +
                "country='" + country + '\'' +
                ", date='" + date + '\'' +
                ", price=" + price +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Now the class where I have defined the logic for GroupBy is the following. It is named `MultipleColumnsGroupBy.java`

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import scala.Tuple2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
public class MultipleColumnsGroupBy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String applicationName = MultipleColumnsGroupBy.class.getName();
        final SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(applicationName).setMaster("local");
        final JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        javaSparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO");

        final ProductSaleEntity productSaleEntity1 = new ProductSaleEntity("Japan", "2019-04-17", 5000.0);
        final ProductSaleEntity productSaleEntity2 = new ProductSaleEntity("USA", "2019-04-16", 10000.0);
        final ProductSaleEntity productSaleEntity3 = new ProductSaleEntity("Japan", "2019-04-17", 3000.0);
        final ProductSaleEntity productSaleEntity4 = new ProductSaleEntity("UK", "2019-04-15", 4000.0);

        final List<ProductSaleEntity> productSaleEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
        productSaleEntityList.add(productSaleEntity1);
        productSaleEntityList.add(productSaleEntity2);
        productSaleEntityList.add(productSaleEntity3);
        productSaleEntityList.add(productSaleEntity4);

        final JavaRDD<ProductSaleEntity> entityJavaRDD = javaSparkContext.parallelize(productSaleEntityList, 1);

        // using groupBy approach
        final JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<ProductSaleEntity>> countryDateToJavaPairEntityRDD =
                entityJavaRDD.groupBy(a -> a.getCountry() + "::" + a.getDate());

        final List<Tuple2<String, Iterable<ProductSaleEntity>>> countryDateToListOfEntity =
                countryDateToJavaPairEntityRDD.collect();
        log.info("countryDateToListOfEntity is = {} ", countryDateToListOfEntity);

        for (final Tuple2<String, Iterable<ProductSaleEntity>> item : countryDateToListOfEntity) {
            log.info("country and Date is = {} ", item._1);
            final Iterator<ProductSaleEntity> iterator = item._2.iterator();
            Double totalPrice = 0.0;

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                final Double currentPrice = iterator.next().getPrice();
                log.info("Current price is = {} ", currentPrice);
                totalPrice += currentPrice;
            }
            log.info("Total price is = {} ", totalPrice);
        }
        // map of what is the count of each unique combinations of Country and Date together
        final Map<String, Long> collectedMapCount = countryDateToListOfEntity.stream().
                collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p._1, p -> p._2.spliterator().getExactSizeIfKnown()));
        log.info("collectedMapCount is = {} ", collectedMapCount.toString());
    }
}
```

Some explanation/key points about the above code:

1. I have set the mode of executing this spark code to `local`.
2. I have initialized the object `productSaleEntity1` using the normal constructor and added it to the list `productSaleEntityList`.
3. I have converted this Java list to `entityJavaRDD` using the `parallelize` method and passing the `numSlices` parameter as 1.
4. After doing the Group by approach, I used the collect operation and get the java list.
5. A simple iteration is done on the list to get the price element and add it to find the Total price for each of the **unique combinations** of Country and Date.
6. At the last stage, I have simply computed the map to find the count for each unique combination of Country and Date.

**Sample output for the above input data:**

```
21/05/27 17:44:38 INFO MultipleColumnsGroupBy: countryDateToListOfEntity is = [(Japan::2019-04-17,[ProductSaleEntity{country='Japan', date='2019-04-17', price=5000.0}, ProductSaleEntity{country='Japan', date='2019-04-17', price=3000.0}]), (USA::2019-04-16,[ProductSaleEntity{country='USA', date='2019-04-16', price=10000.0}]), (UK::2019-04-15,[ProductSaleEntity{country='UK', date='2019-04-15', price=4000.0}])] 
21/05/27 17:44:38 INFO MultipleColumnsGroupBy: country and Date is = Japan::2019-04-17 
21/05/27 17:44:38 INFO MultipleColumnsGroupBy: Current price is = 5000.0 
21/05/27 17:44:38 INFO MultipleColumnsGroupBy: Current price is = 3000.0 
21/05/27 17:44:38 INFO MultipleColumnsGroupBy: Total price is = 8000.0 
21/05/27 17:44:38 INFO MultipleColumnsGroupBy: country and Date is = USA::2019-04-16 
21/05/27 17:44:38 INFO MultipleColumnsGroupBy: Current price is = 10000.0 
21/05/27 17:44:38 INFO MultipleColumnsGroupBy: Total price is = 10000.0 
21/05/27 17:44:38 INFO MultipleColumnsGroupBy: country and Date is = UK::2019-04-15 
21/05/27 17:44:38 INFO MultipleColumnsGroupBy: Current price is = 4000.0 
21/05/27 17:44:38 INFO MultipleColumnsGroupBy: Total price is = 4000.0 
21/05/27 17:44:38 INFO MultipleColumnsGroupBy: collectedMapCount is = {Japan::2019-04-17=2, UK::2019-04-15=1, USA::2019-04-16=1}
```